# Javascript not render in IE

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript

I have this script, it work fine in any browser except IE. I am using IE 11

```
let liItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#DeltaTopNavigation>div>ul>li>ul'));
alert(liItem[0].textContent);

liItem[0].style.borderTop='red';
```

I can't even get alert from code above.

Comment: Anything in the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank guys for feedback. i got working using this:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#DeltaTopNavigation>div>ul>li>ul'), i;

for (i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
  divs[0].style.borderTop='red';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

According to this link [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) , `Array.from` is not supported in IE because its part of ES6 specifications which are not fully supported in IE 11. You need to polyfill it.

Try one of the below polyfills:

NPM link - [array.from](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array.from)

[ES6-shim](https://github.com/paulmillr/es6-shim)

[polyfill.js](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/Array.from)